# How to convert array/object of order data to EDI 850 format?

Tags: php, magento, integration, edi, logistics

I need to build an integration process between a website (Magento in this case) and a warehouse/logistics API.
The warehouse needs to get the data as EDI (850 for order-requests, other numbers for other things).
I know how to prepare the data in other known formats (xml/json/...), but I never used EDI before, so.. how exactly am I supposed to prepare the data?

Thanks in advance!

*I downloaded [sabas/edifact](https://github.com/sabas/edifact) which seems to have a way of converting arrays to EDI, but still, I need to know what to put in that array..

**Here are some specifications from the API docs, how should I use/read that table?
[image]

[image]

Comment: that tool you link to is for edifact. you want to use x12. both are edi protocols, but different.

Comment: hi - just starting to look at the same thing. did you find any solutions and/or what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to export into XML then I would use a tool that converts XML into X12 files. The way it usually works is that you describe the EDI structure and segments using XML fields.

There is several commercial tools available. The best open source solution I've seen is [X12 Parser](https://x12parser.codeplex.com)

The documentation is great so even if you're not in a .Net environment and you're trying to achieve the opposite (XML to X12) you could use it to create your own conversion tool (I created my own using groovy).

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
Any suggestions for a PHP parser? (open source / commercial)